# RedShift Query via SSRS with user parameters: Say WHAT?

Tags: reporting-services, amazon-redshift

[image]I'm trying to create a query that grabs records that fall within a specified time frame, hence `BETWEEN`.  However, I need to do this from an interactive report which user can specify the endDate and startDate parameters.

I've read that RedShift may not necessarily support variables or parameters and that I may need to use temp tables, but my requirements are that users can pass in values.  I'm confused on how using temp tables with pre-defined values allows for in-determinant values to be passed to the base query...

Here's my initial attempt (dont laugh)

```
   prepare prep_select_plan(date)
    AS select TOP 10 * from table WHERE date BETWEEN $1 AND $2;
    EXECUTE prep_select_plan(@startDate);
    EXECUTE prep_select_plan(@endDate);
    DEALLOCATE prep_select_plan;
```

Is there another platform that would allow me to create a web based, interactive report with the ability to have end users enter parameter values?

**Update***
I've attached the dataset properties window to elicit feedback on how to pass value to the RedShift query.

Comment: So I changed the data type from _date_ to _timestamp_ and appended the parameter values with _00:00:00_ and the query started to run, but now I get the errorERROR [22007] [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 22007] SSL SYSCALL error: No error (0x00000000/0) (Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to a database like RedShift or MySQL using ODBC, you have to use a more generic syntax for parameters. Rather than using the @ symbol and the parameter name, you just use a `?` in the query. For example, one line would look like this:

```
EXECUTE prep_select_plan(?);
```

You can map which report parameters go to the query parameters in the parameters tab of the dataset properties. The parameters are simply mapped in the order they appear, you can't reference the same name in multiple places in the query. It's not as user friendly, but SSRS is primarily designed to work with SQL Server.

Comment: @SteveWhite Thanks for the response.  I'll give it a try when I can connect.
just to clairfy, do I used the ordinal posistion for the SSRS dataset properties mapping (i.e. 1,2, ect.).
`prepare prep_select_plan(date)
    AS select TOP 10 * from table WHERE date BETWEEN $1 AND $2;
    EXECUTE prep_select_plan(?);
    EXECUTE prep_select_plan(?);
    DEALLOCATE prep_select_plan;`

Comment: @thundercougarfalcon  Exactly. Each `?` is assigned in order.